# Greasemonkey script to compare a javascript variable with another page's content?

Tags: php, javascript, compare, greasemonkey

Can a Greasemonkey script compare the following script's `Name` variable to a list of members from another site, and make it run some other part of script if the `Name` doesn't match anyone?

```
//alert(Name);
var postHistory = "http://"+regionSlice+".targetforum.com/board/search.php?do=process&searchuser="+Name+"&exactname=1&showposts=1";

var avatar = "http://othersite.com/forum/avatar/" +regionSlice+ "." + Name + ".png"; // creates an avatar

// Replace the old Avatar
$('.user_icon', this).attr('src', avatar);
$('.user_icon', this).wrap('<a href="' + postHistory + '" class="link"></a>');
$('.user_icon', this).attr('width', '80');
$('.user_icon', this).attr('height', '80');
$('.user_icon', this).attr('style', 'position:relative; TOP:7px');
```

This code would be perfect if it would execute below part if `Name` doesn't match any records.

```
var postHistory = "http://"+regionSlice+".targetforum.com/board/search.php?do=process&searchuser="+Name+"&exactname=1&showposts=1";
var avatar = "http://othersite.com/forum/avatar/" +regionSlice+ "." + Name + ".png"; // creates an avatar
var noAvatar = "http://other.com/forum/avatar/questionmark.png";

// Replace the old Avatar
    $('.user_icon', this).attr('src', noAvatar);
    $('.user_icon', this).wrap('<a href="' + postHistory + '" class="link"></a>');
    $('.user_icon', this).attr('width', '80');
    $('.user_icon', this).attr('height', '80');
    $('.user_icon', this).attr('style', 'position:relative; TOP:7px');
```

---

Memberlist at othersite.com/forum/members.php:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("host","user","pass");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("database", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users ORDER BY ID");

    echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>UserName</th>
</tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

---

Here's example part of that page.This part appears 1 to 10 times in one page so `Name` will be checked 1 to 10 times. "Vortexer" is one example of `Name` and two lines below resides the `user_icon`.

```
<div id="edit4767039" style="padding:0px 0px 6px 0px">
  <a name="4767039">&nbsp;</a>

  <div class="forum_post post_frame" id="post4767039">
    <div class="post_hidden_message">
       Comment below rating threshold, click <a href="#">here</a> to show it.
    </div>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="left" valign="top" id="currentPost">
        <div class="avatar_top">
          <div class="avatar" style="padding-top:10px;">

            <big>Vortexer</big>
            <a class="photo">

              <img class="user_icon" src="theme/img/unknown_icon.jpg"/>
              <span class="left_orb">??</span>
              <span class="right_orb"><img src="http://irrelevantserver.com/forum/ui/avatar_right_orb_blue.png" alt=""/></span>
            </a>
            <small>Senior Member</small>
          </div>
          <center>
          <a href="//articles/The_Code" target="_blank"><span class="sca_icon" style="align: center"><img src="http://irrelevantserver.com/images/community/community site/SCA_badge.png" alt="This user has accepted the code, click for more information"/></a></span>
          </center>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="right" valign="top">
        <table class="right_table">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="message_header">
              <!-- status icon and date -->
              <span>1 Day Ago</span>
              <!-- / status icon and date -->
            </div>
            <div class="post_content" id="post_message_4767039">
              <p>This is forum post content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="message_footer">
              <div class="r_block">
                <span class="post_rating">
                <span class="rating_positive">+3</span>
                </span>
                <a href="ratepost.php?postid=4767039&vote=-1" rel="nofollow" class="vote_down_button">
                  <img src="http://irrelevantserver.com/forum/ui/thumbs_down.png" alt=""/>
                </a>
                <a href="ratepost.php?postid=4767039&vote=1" rel="nofollow" class="vote_up_button">
                  <img src="http://irrelevantserver.com/forum/ui/thumbs_up.png" alt=""/>
                </a>
                <a href="newreply.php?do=newreply&amp;p=4767039" class="quick-reply" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://irrelevantserver.com/forum/ui/message_quote_icon.png" alt="Reply With Quote"/></a>
                <a href="editpost.php?do=editpost&amp;p=4767039" name="vB::QuickEdit::4767039"><img src="http://irrelevantserver.com/forum/ui/edit_icon.png" alt="Edit/Delete Message" class="edit_button"/></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Name is fetched with this code:

```
// Replace everypost's avatar
$('.forum_post').each(function(index) {
    name = $('big', this).html();
    //alert($('big', this).html());
    var Name1 = name.replace("\<font ", "");
    var Name2 = Name1.replace("color\=\"\#c98f1a\"\>", "");
    var Name3 = Name2.replace("color=\"green\"\>", "");
    var Name4 = Name3.replace("color=\"red\"\>", "");
    var Name = Name4.replace("</font>", "");
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It's just case of simple "if" statement or one iteration through an array. But where's that "list of members"?

Comment: Yes it's possible, I recommend you use jQuery in your greasmonkey script so you can take advantage of ajax() function to retrieve content from external websites.

Comment: @Miszy
Added member list relative location and source. 

    Nelson. 
How would it need to be coded to get it work with jquery Ajax?

Comment: @Nelson -- jQuery's `ajax` support is built on top of the xmlHttpRequest support built into the browser and thus, not able to work cross domain *by design.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can compare `Name` against content scraped from another web page.  Since it looks to be cross-domain, you must use [`GM_xmlhttpRequest`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) to do this.

From the looks of ***members.php***, it returns a table like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>UserName</th></tr>
    <tr><td>User A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>User B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>User C</td></tr>
    <tr><td>User D</td></tr>
</table>
```

**and nothing else.**
(If it ***does*** return something else, then the selectors in the following code will need to be adjusted.)
I made [a mockup of that HTML at jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/TDcDV/show/).

If you install this Greasemonkey script, you can see that it reads the usernames:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Parse simple AJAX page scrape/fetch
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     'GET',
    url:        'http://fiddle.jshell.net/TDcDV/show/',
    onload:     getUsernamesFromAjax
} );

function getUsernamesFromAjax (respObject) {
    var respDoc     = $(respObject.responseText);
    var userNameTDs = respDoc.find ("td");
    var userNames   = userNameTDs.map ( function () {
        return this.textContent;
    } ).get ();

    alert ("The usernames are: " + userNames);
}
```

(Alerts, "`The usernames are: User A,User B,User C,User D`".)

---

---

Now, as for comparing `Name` to the data, the question is not clear.

1. **Where is `Name` coming from?**
2. Is there more than one `Name` value?  If so, which `.user_icon` node relates with which `Name`?

Link or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to the whole page.

---

**Update:**
Based on the new information, here's what you want the script to do:

1. Replace avatars with an "In progress" image ("throbber") to let user know that we are waiting for AJAX results.
   (AJAX could take several seconds.)
2. Launch AJAX request to an external site for a member list.
3. When the AJAX comes back with the member list:

   1. For names in the member list, replace their avatar.
   2. For names NOT in the member list, replace their avatar with a "no avatar" image.

Here's **a complete script** that does that.
Install the script and then **visit [jsbin.com/awaxap/1](http://jsbin.com/awaxap/1), to see it in action.**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name      _Replace avatars for matching names
// @include   http://jsbin.com/awaxap/*
// @include   http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @resource  waitImg  http://i.cdn.turner.com/money/.element/img/1.0/misc/throbber.gif
// @grant     GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant     GM_getResourceURL
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Replace avatars with an "In progress" image.
var waitImgSrc  = GM_getResourceURL ("waitImg");
$("div.forum_post div.avatar img.user_icon").attr ('src',  waitImgSrc);


//--- Fetch the member list.
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     'GET',
    url:        'http://fiddle.jshell.net/TDcDV/show/',
    onload:     changeUserIconsOfMembers
} );


//--- Replace avatars based on name match.
function changeUserIconsOfMembers (respObject) {
    var respDoc     = $(respObject.responseText);
    var userNameTDs = respDoc.find ("td");
    var userNames   = userNameTDs.map ( function () {
        return $.trim (this.textContent.toLowerCase () );
    } ).get ();

    //--- Replace every post's avatar.
    $('div.forum_post').each ( function (index) {
        //-- text() automatically strips out any <font> cruft, if present.
        var Name        = $('div.avatar big', this). text ();
        //-- Standardize name for comparison.
        Name            = $.trim (Name).toLowerCase ();

        var regionSlice = "";   // where's this come from?
        var postHistory = "http://" + regionSlice
                        + ".targetforum.com/board/search.php?do=process&searchuser="
                        + Name + "&exactname=1&showposts=1"
                        ;
        var avatar      = "http://othersite.com/forum/avatar/" + regionSlice
                        + "." + Name + ".png"
                        ; // creates an avatar

        avatar  = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrzn7.jpg"; // Temp avatar upgrade. ;)

        //--- Was the username not found?
        if (userNames.indexOf (Name) === -1 ) {
            avatar      = "http://other.com/forum/avatar/questionmark.png";
            avatar  = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbOsC.gif"; // Temp avatar upgrade. ;)
        }

        //--- Replace the old Avatar and give it a link to history.
        var userIcon    = $('div.avatar img.user_icon', this);
        userIcon.attr ( {
            src:        avatar,
            width:      '80',
            height:     '80',
            style:      'position:relative; TOP:7px;'
        } );
        userIcon.wrap ('<a href="' + postHistory + '" class="link"></a>');
    } );
}
```

Note the user "Vortexer" is not found, but "User B" is.

Comment: Okay, updated the answer with code showing the name comparison to external webpage data.  Avatars are switched based on the match.

Comment: Thank you. That script worked perfectly. Also I noticed that you wondered where did `regionSlice` come. It's part of script that gives script the sites region prefix from it's hostname.